# Why Spring Tool Suite is showing errors in every line?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

When I start a project in my Spring Tool Suite mixing Spring and Angular 5, STS marks as errors lots of things that should not be an error otherwise....

like in this image:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7duw.png)

Like [ts] Cannot find name 'html'. in an HTML tag, or
[ts] Cannot find name 'doctype'. in the doctype tag

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is going wrong here, but you can disable validations in the preferences, so that way you could at least get rid of the error markers all over the place. If you would prefer a deeper analysis why those error markers appear, pointing to a sample project would help.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I prefer to fix it than disable validations. What do you mean by ....pointing to a sample project would help? Thanks again. This is a JHipster project.

Comment: I mean to share the concrete project that you created and use to get those errors, maybe on GitHub.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks first. Here is the proyect: https://github.com/Tonterias/MessagesApp

Comment: I tried a standard STS 3.9.4 installation, added the Buildship Gradle integration to it (via the Eclipse Marketplace), and imported the project as Gradle project (Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project). After a while, everything is imported, but I don't see any error markers showing up. Opening index.html looks just fine. So maybe the Gradle import did something good here or some other extensions causing your html files to go crazy. Do you use a plain STS 3.9.4 install?

Comment: Yes, I'm using STS 3.9.4. It should be something installed, then. Thanks a lot.